# Parameter values disappear after Job execution in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using a parameterised job in Jenkins and adding like over a 100 parameters in the job. When I run the job after filling the parameter values, the values reset to their defaults. I want the Jenkins job to retain the last filled parameter values in the Job for the next build. So that if there is any error in the job the user can simply change the wrong value and not fill all the parameters once again. Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Rebuilder](https://plugins.jenkins.io/rebuild/)

Click on the **Rebuild button**. A configuration page contains the existing parameters will appear as shown in the below image.

[image]

[image]

**Usage**

> Once you installed this plug-in whenever you execute a **parametrized**
>   build you will get a rebuild button in the left pane of the run as
>   shown in the image. If you want to execute the build with same
>   parameters, rebuild plug-in will allow you to build it through rebuild
>   button.If you want to edit some of the existing parameters, the
>   rebuild plug-in will allow you to edit the existing parameters and
>   build it.

Comment: What if we are running it on schedule and we want the values to persist